# Using XCode 4.2, Is it possible to use Storyboards to make an iOS 4 compatible app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios4, ios5

I have searched for this answer, and have had mixed reviews. Some say it SHOULD be possible (like using ARC), and some say it's not possible. Can anyone give me a definitive answer either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to apple NO. Apple always said storyboarding would only be for iOS5. But prove it to yourself. Start a new project, check use storyboarding, create the project. Then change the target iOS to 4.3 and run, the view will not load.

ARC will run even down to 4.2, though you can't use weak references below 4.3.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up just moving everything out of that project and splicing everything into a new one. Thanks!